# How do I prove that $A \cup (B \cup C)= (A \cup B)\cup C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have an idea about how prove it, can you say me if it's correct or add something to make it more rigorous.

Let $D = A \cup B$ and $E = B\cup C$. Then we want to prove that:
$$
A \cup E =  D \cup C
$$
Let $x \in A \cup E$, then $x \in A \vee x\in E$ but $x \in E \equiv x\in B \cup C$, then $x \in B \vee x \in C$. Finally: $x \in A \vee x\in B \vee x \in C$.

On the other hand let $x \in D \cup C$, then $x \in C \vee x\in D$ but $x \in D \equiv x\in A \cup B$, then $x \in A \vee x \in B$. Finally: $x \in C \vee x\in A \vee x \in B$.

I know I need to use the commutativity of "$\vee$" (or) but I don't know how to put the ideas together in a formal or rigorous way.

If I have an error in writing, you can also tell me please, this is one of my first proofs.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Can't you just use that union is associative?

Comment: http://www.stumblingrobot.com/2015/06/19/prove-the-associative-laws-for-union-and-intersections-of-sets/

Comment: No Bernard,  in class we made a proof/exercise related to union and intersection properties and the teacher said we couldn't use it :(

Comment: You need only associativity of $\lor$, which you can obtain from truth tables.

Comment: If you need to use the commutativity of “or”, then can’t you just commute your last line to be in the same order as your conclusion of the left hand side of the equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can more concisely use $\iff$ viz.$$\begin{align}x\in A\cup(B\cup C)&\iff x\in A\lor(x\in B\cup C)\\&\iff x\in A\lor(x\in B\lor x\in C)\\&\color{blue}{\iff}(x\in A\lor x\in B)\lor x\in C\\&\iff(x\in A\cup B)\lor(x\in C)\\&\iff x\in(A\cup B)\cup C,\end{align}$$where the blue step uses the tautology $p\lor(q\lor r)\equiv(p\lor q)\lor r$. If you need to prove this tautology, one way is to identify true with $1$ and false with $0$ so $\lor=\max$, and then$$p\lor(q\lor r)=\max\{p,\,\max\{q,\,r\}\}=\max\{p,\,q,\,r\}=\max\{\max\{p,\,q\},\,r\}=(p\lor q)\lor r.$$